# Q: django-simple-menu - menu doesn't load

Tags: python, django

my django-simple-menu doesn't work. My code very closely resembles the example from the doku https://django-simple-menu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#usage-example.

The page loads without the menu links and I get no errors messages. Would be grateful for any ideas on how to solve this.

Django: 3.0.1

Python: 3.7.5

**nav.html**

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            {% for item in menu %} 
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
</nav>
```

**base.html**

```
{% load menu %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
...
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/base.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}

        <div class="d-flex bg-dark header " >
            <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1 bg-dark "> </div>
            <div class="p-2  bg-dark ">User:  {{ user.username }} </div>
            <div class="p-2 bg-dark"><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></div>
        </div>
        {% generate_menu %}
     {% with menu=menus.main %}{% include 'nav.html' %}{% endwith %}

    {% else %}
        ....
    {% endif %}

    <main>
       ...
    </main>

</body>
</html>
```

**setttings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for nsap project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '+hari9jxke*m!4os*6gc!4ygk_hr5es-qdx)x=qza7)7m&x&%='

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'userManagement.apps.UsermanagementConfig',
    'doppik.apps.DoppikConfig',
    'base.apps.BaseConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'menu',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR + '/nsap/templates/',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# USER Model

#AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.User'

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
PROJECT_NAME = 'nsap'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, PROJECT_NAME, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, PROJECT_NAME, 'static/')

#MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
#MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..','..', 'media'))


# Loging

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

**menus.py**

```
from menu import Menu, MenuItem
from django.urls import reverse

Menu.add_item("main", MenuItem("Booking",
                               reverse("doppik.views.booking"),
                               weight=10,
                               icon="tools"))

Menu.add_item("main", MenuItem("ShowAccount",
                               reverse("doppik.views.show_accounts"),
                               weight=10,
                               icon="tools"))

Menu.add_item("main", MenuItem("Login",
                               reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
                               check=lambda request: not request.user.is_authenticated()))       

Menu.add_item("main", MenuItem("Logout",
                               reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
                               check=lambda request: request.user.is_authenticated()))
```

Edit: 
I think the problem is that menus.py is not running and no MenuItems are added to Menu.

I have added the command print("foo") to the menus.py file. The output does not display in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the pip installed build, or have you tried this fork that has Django 2.2 support? https://github.com/skunkie/django-simple-menu/ I imagine the original build may have some compatibility issues.

Comment: I've running the pip installed build and i tested the fork. Both doesn't work. 

There modified the example project in the fork, not the simple-menu part.